# How to ensure the expiry of a stream data structure in redis is set once only?

Tags: java, redis, lettuce

I have a function that use `lettuce` to talk to a redis cluster.

In this function, I insert data into a stream data structure.

```
import io.lettuce.core.cluster.SlotHash;

...

public void addData(Map<String, String> dataMap) {

var sync = SlotHash.getSlot(key).sync()

sync.xadd(key, dataMap);

}
```

I also want to set the ttl when I insert a record for the first time. It is because part of the user requirement is expire the structure after a fix length of time. In this case it is 10 hour.

Unfortunately the `XADD` function does not accept an extra parameter to set the TTL like the `SET` function.

So now I am setting the ttl this way:

```
public void addData(Map<String, String> dataMap) {

var sync = SlotHash.getSlot(key).sync()

sync.xadd(key, dataMap);
sync.expire(key, 60000 /* 10 hours */); 

}
```

What is the best way to ensure the I will set the expiry time only once (i.e. when the stream structure is first created)? I should not set TTL multiple times within the function because every call to `xadd` will also follow by a call of `expire` which effectively  postpone the expiry time indefinitely.

I think I can always check the number of items in the stream data structure but it is an overhead. I don't want to keep flags in the java application side because the app could be restarted and this information will be removed from the memory.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try lua script, sample script below which sets the expiry only if it's not set for key, works with any type of key in redis.

```
eval "local ttl = redis.call('ttl', KEYS[1]); if ttl == -1 then redis.call('expire', KEYS[1], ARGV[1]); end; return ttl;" 1 mykey 12
```

script also returns the actual expiry time left in seconds.